# Excel macro to paste data into column X

Tags: excel, range, offset, vba

I am looking for a macro to paste some data onto a moving range. I already have a cell that tells me the number of the next non empty column and this is the code I currently use:

```
Dim OpenFileName As String
Dim wb As Workbook

'Select and Open workbook
OpenFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename()
If OpenFileName = "False" Then Exit Sub
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(OpenFileName)

'Get data EXAMPLE
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Teleselling 17").Range("I9:I289")*this should be dynamic, I want to paste data in a moving range*.Value = wb.Sheets("TELESELLING INBOUND").Range("L9:L289").Value

wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

MsgBox ("Done!")
```

Comment: What do you mean by a "moving range"?

Comment: Everytime I paste data from the Teleselling inbound sheet I want to do it in a range which moves everytime I fill it with data

Comment: Moves where???  Do you just want to paste it below the last used cell in column I?  Or do you want it to paste it into a new column?  (Your question says something about you worked out how to find the next non-empty column, but that doesn't seem to be used anywhere in your code.)  Or are you just trying to allow for a "moving" end-row in your source and destination areas?  Or ...?

Answer (score 1):

Use the newly opened workbook/worksheet/range to define the scope of the value transfer.

```
with wb.workSheets("TELESELLING INBOUND").Range("L9:L289")
    ThisWorkbook.workSheets("Teleselling 17").Range("XFD9").end(xltoleft).offset(0, 1).resize(.rows.count, .columns.count) = .value
end with
```

Comment: I guess that's as good an interpretation of "moving range" as any.  :D  (But I wonder where the cell giving the number of the next **non-**empty column comes into play?)

Comment: As it was noticeably missing from the question beyond a vague off-handed reference, I inferred that it was in fact a closely guarded secret and I did not want to risk treason.